# Width and Height Animation with Pose on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, popmotion

I really love to use [pose](https://popmotion.io/pose/) on react native because it's really easy. But I got some small issues. My question is; is there any way to use pose on react native to make animations with **width**, **height** or **padding**? I made some animations with **position**, **opacity** or **transform** but I couldn't figure it out with width.

I wrote a small example code below to understand better.

Example Code;

```
import React from 'react';
import posed from 'react-native-pose';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export const SearchBoxAnimated = posed.View({
  getBigger: { x: -16, width: '100%' },
  normal: { x: 0, width: '85%' }
});

const SearchBox = ({isGetBigger}) => (
   <View>
      <SearchBoxAnimated pose={isGetBigger ? 'getBigger' : 'normal'} />
   </View>
);
```

When I try this, It gives an error.

`Error: Style property 'width' is not supported by native animated module.`

Package Versions:

- React native: 0.55.4
- Expo: 30.0.1
- React: 16.3.1
- React native pose: 0.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main limitation in react native  is that you can only animate non-layout properties, I suggest you to use the [transform](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms) property, which might work in this case.